# Kamma and (psychiatric) delusions / madness

Tags: karma

if I am mad and my action would not have been performed if not for loss of reality (i.e. psychosis) will I still bear its -ve fruit?

As a Buddhist or otherwise.

Please answer sensitively :)

Answer (score 2):

**"The Pali term Karma literally means action or doing. Any kind of intentional action whether mental, verbal, or physical, is regarded as Karma"**

You have to look at the action (good or bad) and the  consequence( Kamma & vipaka). whether one has a sound mind or unsound mind doesn't matter, without intention there is no action.

Even a person suffering from psychosis uses his mind to do things,  so without thoughts nothing good or bad  happens( the thoughts may be abnormal,incomplete,unclear or confusing)  ,but a person with psychosis may not feel the consequences like a normal person ,so the magnitude of suffering may differ for the same actions committed by different people.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with jathin's answer. There was a case in my country a few years ago, where someone on a bus cut off someone else's head. They did that, because they thought that they were sitting next to a devil. The criminal justice trial found them "not guilty of murder by reason of diminished responsibility", they were remanded for psychiatric care, and later released (with anti-psychotic medication).

I'm not sure I know about kamma but I think that intention follows from view, and if your view is psychotic (e.g. if you think you're sitting next to a devil) then I'm not sure.
I slightly doubt whether Buddhism would recommend you kill even a "devil" if you meet one: but still.

I think that the Vinaya (see [page 74 through 86](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1.pdf)) identifies what constitutes murder:

- Object: the victim must have been human
- Intention and perception: the assailant must have intended to cause death
- Effort: the assailant must have done something to cause death
- Result: the victim had to actually die as a result

I'm not sure whether the Vinaya rule is the same as "kamma", but I'd argue that psychosis may prevent intention and/or perception.

In my country, an adult who is psychotic may be given a court-appointed legal guardian -- that is, if they're unable to make informed decisions, if they cannot give informed consent, because they are:

- Unable to understand the choices available to them
- Unable to understand the likely consequences of each choice.

The [first story of the Dhammapada](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=001) is about someone who couldn't see with their eyes. Maybe someone with psychosis cannot properly see with their mind (and cannot form criminal intent).